# LoadLibrary и ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT

Tags: winapi, dll, masm32, library

Здравствуйте. Ситуация такая, нужно вызвать функцию beep из kernel32 с помощью как не удивительно loadlibrary. Сам kernel32 находится в папке с программой и имеет просто другое название (всё это, исключительно для примера подключения "типа" программной dll и работа с ней). Всё вроде-бы должно было бы идти как по маслу, но тут постоянно выскакивает ошибка в отладчике, попробовал по разному в программе прописать путь к библиотеке ("mylib","mylib.dll",""\mylib.dll"","E:\masm32\prog\mylib.dll"), но увы ни как программа не хочет конектится с dll и выводит такую ошибку:

> 000000C1 (ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT)

Вот собственно сам код:

```
mov hDll, rv(LoadLibrary, chr$("E:\masm32\BugsFinder\mylib.dll"))

mov ptrInstr, rv(GetProcAddress, hDll, chr$("Beep"))
```

Что делать помогите пожалуйста :(

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ваш EXE вообще после сборки импорты имеет? Выводит ошибку кто именно? В вашем коде нет ни проверки кодов возврата, ни вывода ошибок.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я всё смотрю в аналоге OllyDbg

Comment: А импорты-то в программе есть? Ну и GetLastError после LoadLibrary дерните. Как-то я не верю в код ошибки без его вызова...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в смысле импорты, можно по подробнее? Скрин добавил

Comment: Директория Import в MZPE. Но судя по скрину импорты определенно есть. А mylib.dll у вас под какую разрядность загружается? Подозреваю, что она 64-битная...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну да, винда же 64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя грузить из 32-битного процесса (а у вас на скрине именно он) 64-битную DLL. Грузите 32-битную DLL и будет вам счастье.